# "Windows could not connect to the System Event Notification Service service"

Tags: windows-7, event-log, boot

Yesterday, everything was fine. I didn't install anything, add any device or changed any setting that I can recall. I shut the system off cleanly and went to sleep.

Obviously, that means my fully updated copy of Windows 7 Professional fails to log me in today. After successfully entering my credential, I am greeted by the following error message:

> Windows could not connect to the System Event Notification Service service.

Clicking okay makes the message go away... and that's it. I had to shut off the system to try again.

Yes, after reboot I had the same issue.

Yes, I can log in just fine in safe mode.

Yes, I have looked into the event log. Nothing interesting *that I could see*, except an event log entry stating the System Event Notification Service did enter the running mode successfully.

What god did I anger and what can I do to mollify him and regain access to my computer?

Comment: I recognize that emoticon from FAO. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I did nothing to cause the issue and nothing was required to be done to fix the error.

Just after I posted this question, I tried rebooting the system again and this time it logged me in just fine.

I'm sorry, Googlers, I'm as stumped as you are.

Comment: This is not an answer, rather a comment or an edit to your question. I suggest you change it.

Comment: @Xavier, I think "Try rebooting again, it'll help although I don't know why" qualifies as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

From an administrative cmd prompt run `netsh winsock reset`.